# Solr Error instantiating class: Custom Class

Tags: java, solr, filter, lucene

I am using Solr 5.0.0,
I have created one custom class as given below.

My filter is given below

```java
package com.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute;

public class CustomFilter extends TokenFilter {

    protected CustomFilter(TokenStream input) {
        super(input);
    }

    private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    private final OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);

    @Override
    public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        // .............................................
        // .............................................
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
    }
}
```

And my filter factory is given below

```java
package com.myorg;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;

public class MyCustomFilter extends TokenFilterFactory {

    public MyCustomFilter(Map<String, String> args) {
        super(args);
    }
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream ts) {
        return new CustomFilter(ts);
    }
}
```

And i have added this class to the schema.xml

```xml
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="com.myorg.MyCustomFilter"/>
</analyzer>
```

I made one jar file from the above classes have added this to my Solr installation Directory  `solr-5.0.0/server/solr/MYCORE/lib`

Here MYCORE is my core name and added this path to solrconfig.xml like this `<lib dir="../lib" />`

But when i restart my Solr its giving error like

```
`Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_wslc": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'com.myorg.MyCustomFilter'`.
```

Why this happens?

Comment: What is the code you have left out from `MyCustomFilter`? Do you use any classes from libraries there? Are the imports of `MyCustomFilter` complete or did you omit something there too? I ask because you need to provide additional libraries together with your plugin in the lib folder.

Comment: @cheffe lucene-core-5.0.0
lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.1  are the jars used. 
Inside my core directory one lib directory is there, and i just put  only my jar there. No other jar.
is it the right place to place my lib? I mean lib directory  Inside my core directorydirectory

Comment: Why aren't you using the [lucene-analyzers-common in the proper version 5.0.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/5.0.0)? The Lucene/Solr guys have introduce a new major version (going from 4.X to 5.X) because they do **breaking changes**. Switch that to the right version.

Answer (score 1):

Cheffe is right - Solr 5.X is not compatible with Solr 4.x when it comes to plugins/extensions - you need to change your dependencies to use Solr/Lucene 5.x libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your schema, does it have a field type named "text_wslc" ? You have not defined that fieldType or something

Comment: I have defined that field, but its about instantiating class: 'com.myorg.MyCustomFilter